# Using google calendar I'm trying to get all event but every time get error message like "Not Found". What is error in Api?

Tags: google-calendar-api

I tried get list of event from calendar example from here https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list No matter which property I use, I always get the 404 "not found" error. Anyone can shed some light on this? Many thanks!!!

```
POST: "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/oneclapp.2021@gmail.com/events? key=AIzaSyCGRPF0wSSBLndqdUftlbsDH9emHD_S-qg

Accept: "application/json" 

Authorization:  Bearer ya29.a0ARrdaM9PPHndl040qaXFmoSFGT9yRPWZs_yrTnYLAHQ0GF-UBvGc67S2L1m0O5OFIilq8oVGRuvw29NFwomtmUTBeHoABcIlaVD_p--4NVlBWCcXLBgfDjsF_5tvt4XRShd1itpe_9CULan9x6BV4TOyP__TkQ

Response:
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "not Found",
    "message": "Not Found"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Not Found"
 }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google calendar api get error like "domain": "global", "reason": "notFound", "message": "Not Found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68677318/google-calendar-api-get-error-like-domain-global-reason-notfound-me)

Answer (score 0):

Upon checking the erros [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/errors#404_not_found), it seems that "Not Found" issue is there and means:

> The specified resource was not found.

Most common examples of it are:

- Resource/ID not existing
- You don't have access to the calendar.

I noticed some issues with the one in your post:

- `key` has a space before it. Removing that space if it wasn't a typo.

[image: key]

- Upon checking `Try this API` and inputted the email you used, it did convert `@` to `%40`, you can also apply that one. This would explain that the resource did not exist (invalid) and you don't have access to it as it is invalid.

[image: email]