# Google calendar api get error like "domain": "global", "reason": "notFound", "message": "Not Found"

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I tried get list of event from calendar example from [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list).
No matter which property I
use, I always get the 404 "not found" error. Anyone can shed some light on this? Many thanks.

Request.

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/oneclapp.2021@gmail.com/events? 
    key=AIzaSyCGRPF0wSSBLndqdUftlbsDH9emHD_S-qg
 Accept: "application/json"
    Authorization:  Bearer ya29.a0ARrdaM9PPHndl040qaXFmoSFGT9yRPWZs_yrTnYLAHQ0GF-UBvGc67S2L1m0O5OFIilq8oVGRuvw29NFwomtmUTBeHoABcIlaVD_p--4NVlBWCcXLBgfDjsF_5tvt4XRShd1itpe_9CULan9x6BV4TOyP__TkQ
```

Response

```
Response:
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "not Found",
    "message": "Not Found"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Not Found"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First off [events.list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list) is not HTTP Post its a HTTP GET

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/events
```

Second assuming that you just miss wrote post and you are actually doing a http get.

Not found means just that the currently authenticated user does not have access to the calendar that you are trying to request events for. in this case  `oneclapp.2021@gmail.com`

I recommend using primary to test that you can get the currently authenticated users primary calendar.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events
```

Comment: GET : https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events using this api get list of event, but still GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/events this api occurs same error as above and all other api gives same error {
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "notFound",
                "message": "Not Found"
            }
        ],
        "code": 404,
        "message": "Not Found"
    }
}

Comment: Thats because calendarid is not a calendar id for the user who you are authorized for you need their calendar id which is why i suggested you use primary.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have not configured the OAuth 2.0 Client IDs correctly. We need to configure the OAuth client ID correctly and its type should be 'Web Application'. I was also getting the same error messages, but once I configured the OAuth ID, then it started working.

OAuth id type: Web Application

[Permission scopes](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/get#auth) : https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events.readonly, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events

Authorized redirect URIs: http://localhost

Here is the screenshot of the Google Calendar API project settings.
[image]